# Is it possible to specify which tests are run with `python setup.py test`?

Tags: python, testing

Is it possible to specify which tests are run with `python setup.py test`? For example I'd like to do something like this:

```
python setup.py test my_test_module.MyTestClass.my_test_method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out

```
python -m unittest tests.my_test_module.MyTestClass.my_test_method
```